# CSS only Typewriter animation over multiple Lines

Tags: css, css-animations

I made this Typewriter effect. It has the problem that it continues going right one more time then it should. Also I'm wondering how i could make this effect with the text splitted in two lines (The text splitted into 2 Lines for Responsive reasons).

Thanks for your help. :)

```css
.dynamictext {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dynamictext li {
  color: #000;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  animation: slide 16s steps(4) infinite;
}
@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    top: -280px;
  }
}
.dynamictext li span {
  position: relative;
}
.dynamictext li span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  animation: typing 4s steps(55) infinite;
}
@keyframes typing {
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0 -1em 0 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dynamictext">
    <li><span>1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>4Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check this: https://dev.to/afif/a-multi-line-css-only-typewriter-effect-3op3

Comment: @TemaniAfif already looked at this. Problem is the Change of content when using this codesnippet.